# Unable to access element in JSON when keyname is unknown

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to retrieve the filename of gists on Github, from the data obtained from Github's API. I'm using javascript to access the data.

An example result can be found here: https://api.github.com/users/blaercom/gists. I've also copied a shortened version of the data below.

```
{
  ...
  id: "4468273",
  files: {
    firstpost.md: {
      type: "text/plain",
      filename: "firstpost.md",
      size: 16,
      language: "Markdown"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I've been trying many things, but I can't seem to access the filename. This is because the 'files' object is not a list, but a key-value pair, where the key identifier matches the filename itself.

Things I've tried include

```
filename = files[0]['filename']
filename = files[0].filename
filename = files['filename']
```

Frankly, the only methods that work are variations of `filename = files['firstpost.md']['filename']` but this isn't valid since I can not know the filename beforehand.

I'm sure it is possible to access the filename, but have been spending quite a while testing different methods. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: That's not valid JSON. `firstpost.md` has a dot in it which is not allowed.

Comment: It's valid since it's inside `""`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera No, not the one in quotes, the one above!

Comment: @LeeTaylor, it's valid. Check the json on [this site](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), just paste [this link](https://api.github.com/users/blaercom/gists) in the  `JSON Data URL` box and then click `process`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera Yes, that's valid. But the JSON above is **NOT** valid. I am commenting on the supplied JSON above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a real example using your `json` response

```
var obj='your json data';
var fileNames=[];
for(var i in obj[0]['files'])
{
    var fileName=obj[0]['files'][i]['filename'];
    fileNames.push(fileName);
}
document.write(fileNames[0]); // firstpost.md
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xwXUv/1/).

**Update:**

[**Another example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xwXUv/2/) using `jsonp/script`.

```
<script src="https://api.github.com/users/blaercom/gists?callback=myCallback"></script>
```

The callback function

```
function myCallback(o)
{
    var obj=o.data;
    var fileNames=[];
    for(var i in obj[0]['files'])
    {
        var fileName=obj[0]['files'][i]['filename'];
        fileNames.push(fileName);
    }
    document.write(fileNames[0]);  // firstpost.md
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `for (var key in object) {}`, here is an example using the data from your [api call](https://api.github.com/users/blaercom/gists):

```
var filenames = [];

for (var filename in data[0].files) {
   filenames.push(filename);
}

console.log(filenames); // ["firstpost.md"]
```

Comment: You think you can have a key called `firstpost.md` in JSON?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Yes, but only with quotes. The json response from the api call is correct: https://api.github.com/users/blaercom/gists

Comment: OK. So why has the OP removed the quotes for the supplied JSON?! Very odd!

Comment: Ok I apologize for that. I use a Chrome plugin that displays JSON for me, which automatically removes the quotes. I checked the 'raw' JSON and indeed it appeared with quotes. Sorry again